# Get Error 500 when deploying a new code using Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, apache, symfony, opcache

What happens, I have a SYMFONY 2.8 production system, it receives updates from my packages "BUNDLES" through to "pull" automatic. and for some reason the server to error 500, complaining of cached code.

I do not cache on apache and not use another caching system, PHP 6.5.24 use this linux server.

This is an example of the error that occurs when the server receives an update.

```
[Wed Aug 24 17:05:11.638885 2016] [:error] [pid 11055] [client 64.16.214.100:30866] PHP Fatal error:

Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException' with message 'Circular reference detected for service "service_name", path: 
"service_name".' in /home/my_system/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2191\nStack trace:\n#0 /tmp/my_system/prod/cache/classes.php(2460): 
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('service_name')\n#1 /tmp/my_system/prod/cache/classes.php(2428): 
Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->lazyLoad('kernel.exceptio...')\n#2 /tmp/my_system/prod/cache/classes.php(2275): 
Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->getListeners('kernel.exceptio...')\n#3 /home/my_system/app/bootstrap.php.cache(3265): 
Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.exceptio...', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent))\n#4 /home/my_system/app/bootstrap.php.cache(3213): 
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exc in /home/my_system/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2191
```

How to solve the problem? I restart the Apache service. Now I would like to understand and solve it with the help of you as I can be doing something wrong in this process.

Run the following command every time I send an update:

```
composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console assets:install --symlink --env=prod --no-debug
```

But still does not solve the problem, as I said before I can only solve if I restartar the apache service.

Thank you all

Comment: Which are the `service_name` dependencies ?

Comment: This name is the name of a service that created the problem only when Occurs send a code update is the solution I have so far is restart the Apache service, it's like the old code to stay in cache.

Comment: Service code: `# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html
parameters:
#    parameter_name: value


services:
#    service_name:
#        class: AppBundle\Directory\ClassName
#        arguments: ["@another_service_name", "plain_value", "%parameter_name%"]
   service_name:
       class: MOB\CPMEBundle\EventListener\ErrorRedirect
       arguments:
            ['@router']
       tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }`

Comment: Do you have the opcache extension enabled? It will cache files for configured number of seconds (which is good for perfmormance). The following command should return output if you do: `php -m | grep -i opcache`

Comment: Yes I have installed OPCACHE you know how I can get around this problem as it is an inconvenience every time I send a code to the server, have you restartar the apache service. @JakubZalas ?

Answer (score 0):

Does not seem to be a cache problem to me, but rather a conflict of dependencies.

For example, if service Aservice has a dependency on Bservice, which depends on Cservice. And Cservice depends on Aservice. 
In this case appears circle dependency which cannot be resolved.

In my case I had this problem with Doctrine Event Listeners, for example. Check out your code if you had a similar circle of dependencies.

Comment: Is cache Yes. Because I access the server and restarto the apache service and back to work.